# Test of interaction in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, interaction

I know that it's pretty much impossible to test out all the combinations of interaction with sufficiently many predictors, but if I were to suspect some interaction between two particular predictors how would I go about testing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that your predictors are $x_1,x_2, ... , x_n$ and response $y$. To test interaction between two variables, say, $x_1$ and $x_2$ in `R`, add `x1:x2` (interaction term) to the right of the `glm()` function. For example:

```
glmfit <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2 + ..., mydataset, family = "binomial")
```

Or:

```
glmfit <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2 + ..., mydataset) # x1*x2 = x1 + x2 + x1:x2
```

Now see if *coefficient* for `x1:x2` is large and significant enough from `summary(glmfit)` output.